# 2 divs hover effect, one img blur, other one text hover

Tags: css, html, hover, blur

when I move my mouse over a picture it should blur (via CSS) and at the same time it should appear a text. So far, so good, but when I move my mouse on the image where actually the (still invisible) text is, only the text appears, but the image isn't going to be blurred.

http://jsfiddle.net/u8eY7/

My Code:

```
    <li><div id="blurbox"><div class="blur img"><div class="img-wrap"><div class="img-info">
                 Wilkinson <br />
                 Afterglow <br />
                 RAM Records <br />
                 13.</div>
              <img src="images/cover/01-wilkinson-afterglow.png" class="hover" width="168" height="168"></div></div></div><div id="caption">

    .blur img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: 1s all;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index:11;
}


    .blur img:hover {
        -webkit-filter: blur(18px);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 168px;
        height: 168px;
        position: relative;
        border:3px solid white;
        opacity: 0.6;
        z-index:11;
    }

    .blur img:hover .img-info {
        -webkit-filter: blur(18px);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 168px;
        height: 168px;
        position: relative;
        border:3px solid white;
        opacity: 0.6;
        z-index:11;
    }

    .img-wrap{
        height:168px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
        width:168px;
    }
    .img-info{
        bottom:0;
        color:#fff;
        opacity:0;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
    z-index:12;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}
.img-info h4, .img-info p{
padding:0 0px;
}
.img-wrap:hover .img-info{
    opacity:0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 75);
    transition:opacity 1.75s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1.75s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1.75s;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code?

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? I'm not sure I follow the issue when I tried to reproduce what you stated

Comment: sorry http://jsfiddle.net/u8eY7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
.blur img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(18px);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 168px;
    height: 168px;
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index:11;
}
```

with

```
.img-wrap:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(18px);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 168px;
    height: 168px;
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index:11;
}
```

remove this as it will never be applied and is not useful according to your html structure

```
.blur img:hover .img-info {
        -webkit-filter: blur(18px);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 168px;
        height: 168px;
        position: relative;
        border:3px solid white;
        opacity: 0.6;
        z-index:11;
    }
```

i hope this is what you want. Like you had given for img-info  the image should also get the hover when hovered over .img-wrap and do not use classes as hover and img . It would be confusing when you write styles.